# FXML application, switching between screens?

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I only just made my first FXML application as a test that involved making a simple log in screen. I am now about to try and make a full application, I'm just a little unsure on how it is supposed to be done. What is the correct way to switch between screens?

Answer (score 0):

I use always the same Parent node (BorderPane, for example), and just change the nodes inside.

Suppose you have:

```
Node screen1;
Node screen2;
```

Then in the case of the borderPane:

```
borderPane.setCenter(screen1); // This changes to screen 1
// ...
borderPane.setCenter(screen2); // This changes to screen 2
```